# using ansible expect to create nessus user (nessuscli)

Tags: python, automation, ansible, pexpect

I'm using ansible expect to create a user for my nessus (by using the nessuscli). the expect should answer few question as below (I added the numbers 1-5). My expect get stuck at number 5. the last letters of number 5 is the "(the user can have an empty rules set)" and then the next line (carriage return). This makes the issue as I dont know how to tell expect that there is a phrase that is followed by a next line. I tried \r \n and none of them worked! any healp is appreciated.

Also, you can see my ansible code below.

Thanks

you can see the screenshot of the nessus cli propmt here:
[screenshot of nessucli propmpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC22E.png)

============ Nessuscli adduser Prompt(s) ==========

1- Login:

2- Login password:

3- Login password (again):

4- Do you want this user to be a Nessus 'system administrator' user (can upload plugins, etc.)? (y/n) [n]: y

5- User rules

nessusd has a rules system which allows you to restrict the hosts
that test has the right to test. For instance, you may want
him to be able to scan his own host only.

Please see the Nessus Command Line Reference for the rules syntax

Enter the rules for this user, and enter a BLANK LINE once you are done :
(the user can have an empty rules set)

===================================================

My Ansible Code:

name: create nessus user

```
expect:
  command: /opt/nessus/sbin/nessuscli adduser
  responses:
    'Login: ': "{{nessus_username}}" # answer number 1
    'Login password: ': "{{nessus_pass}}" # answer number 2
    'Login password \(again\): ': "{{nessus_pass}}" # answer number 3
    '\[n\]: ': 'y' # answer number 4
    'set\)\\n ': "\n" # answer number 5 which doesnt work
    '\[n\]: ': 'y' # answer the next propmpt (not in question and works)
```

Comment: Try installing `expect` on the target machine (temporarily if necessary). Expect includes a utility called `autoexpect`. Run this, and then run `nessuscli adduser` command to completion. Finally, type `exit`. `autoexpect` will now have created an expect script called `script.exp` in your current working directory. You can look in here to see the patterns required in each step. Hopefully this will help you figure out what you are missing.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Under `Nessuscli adduser Prompt(s)`, you have #4 as `Do you want this user to be a Nessus 'system administrator' user (can upload plugins, etc.)?`, but you just have `\[n\]: ` as your prompt.  And for #5, which is `User rules`, you have `set)`.  It does not seem that your responses match your prompts.

Answer (score 2):

After much tinkering, this did it for me:

```
  - name: Add user
    expect:
      echo: yes
      timeout: 5
      command: "{{ nessus_cli_bin }} adduser"
      responses:
        (.*)Login(.*): "{{ nessus_user }}"
        (.*)Login password(.*): "{{ nessus_pass }}"
        (.*)Login password(.*): "{{ nessus_pass }}"
        (.*)system administrator(.*): "y"
        (.*)rules set(.*): "\n"
        (.*)ok(.*): "y"
```