# Using expect to create the Nessus user

Tags: linux, automation, ansible, rhel, nessus

How can I do the same thing as done here [using ansible expect to create nessus user (nessuscli)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54322358/using-ansible-expect-to-create-nessus-user-nessuscli) without using Ansible ?
I am trying following with no luck:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -5

spawn /opt/nessus/sbin/nessuscli adduser

expect "(.*)Login(.*):\r"

send -- "admin\r"

expect "(.*)Login password(.*)\r" send -- "password\r"

expect "(.*)Login password(.*)\r" send -- "password\r"

expect "(.*)system administrator(.*)\r" send -- "y\r"

expect "(.*)rules set(.*):\r" send -- "\n\r"

expect "(.*)ok(.*):\r" send -- "y\r"

expect eof
```

Comment: Hello, what is the error you getting ? can you share the error ? Also, can you add the execution result ?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the answer you linked to does not contain `\r` sequences inside the expect match expressions, nor does [a more traditional example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect#Usage)

Thus, I suspect you will get a lot further by removing the `\r` sequences from the `expect` blocks:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -5

spawn /opt/nessus/sbin/nessuscli adduser

expect "(.*)Login(.*):"
send -- "admin\r"

expect "(.*)Login password(.*)"
send -- "password\r"

expect "(.*)Login password(.*)"
send -- "password\r"

expect "(.*)system administrator(.*)"
send -- "y\r"

expect "(.*)rules set(.*):"
send -- "\n\r"

expect "(.*)ok(.*):"
send -- "y\r"

expect eof
```